# App crashes when setting custom Struct value in AppStorage

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, appstorage

I have a custom struct I want to store in `AppStorage`:

```
struct Budget: Codable, RawRepresentable {

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case total, spent
    }

    var total: Double
    var spent: Double

    init(total: Double = 5000.0, spent: Double = 3000.0) {
        self.total = total
        self.spent = spent
    }

    init?(rawValue: String) {
        guard let data = rawValue.data(using: .utf8),
              let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Budget.self, from: data)
        else { return nil }

        self = result
    }

    var rawValue: String {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self),
              let result = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        else {
            return ""
        }

        return result
    }

}
```

I then have the following view:

```
struct DemoView: View {

    @AppStorage(UserDefaults.StorageKeys.budget.rawValue) var budget = Budget()

    var body: some View {
        Button("Update") {
            budget.total = 10
        }
    }
}
```

When I tap the button the app crashes with `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on `guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self)` for `rawValue` in `Budget`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Don’t use try? Use do try catch with print(error) in the catch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are running into infinite recursion. This is because types that conforms to both `Encodable` and `RawRepresentable` automatically get [this `encode(to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rawrepresentable/encode(to:)-4evma) implementation ([source](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Codable.swift#L4585)), which encodes the raw value. This means that when you call `JSONEncoder().encode`, it would try to call the getter of `rawValue`, which calls `JSONEncoder().encode`, forming infinite recursion.

To solve this, you can implement `encode(to:)` explicitly:

```
func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(total, forKey: .total)
    try container.encode(spent, forKey: .spent)
}
```

Note that you should also implement `init(from:)` explicitly, because you also get a `init(from:)` implementation ([source](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Codable.swift#L4599)) that tries to decode your JSON as a single JSON string, which you certainly do not want.

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    total = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .total)
    spent = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .spent)
}
```